# Given two matrices find change of basis matrix

Tags: linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Assume there is a matrix $B$ representing a linear transformation in an unknown basis and a matrix A representing that same transformation in standard basis.
How to find the unknown basis or the change of basis matrix $T$?
$B = T^{-1} . A . T$

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an impossible (or rather ambiguous) task.

For example the identity matrix is the representing matrix of the identity map with respect to **any** basis. A similar thing holds true for the zero matrix. So in general there may be different bases, for which $B$ is the correct representing matrix. Hence the best you could possibly do is to find **some** basis, for which $B$ is the right matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right of course. One might specify more requirements, for example det(T) = 1. It works in parts with mathematica on small matrices.

Comment: You are welcome. The identity matrix does have determinant 1 though. I don’t see an obvious criterion making the basis for $B$ essentially unique.